# Monitoring tool for several Macs on a network?

Tags: software-recommendation, monitoring

Is there a tool like [iStats Menu 3](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) which could show me the same kind of information (hard drive statistics, sensors state, network usage) for every machine running OS X on my network?

Or even better, for every machine running any OS (or at least some kind of Unix)?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Remote Desktop does this (and more).